# Como pasar el contenido de jquery de una variable a otra para ser enviada por ajax a un documento php?

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo 
proceso.js

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.Carpeta = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        codigoI: false,
        };

    this.each(function () {
        var crear = $(this);

         if (options.input) {
          $(createInput).find('.confirm').click(function () {                       
                if ($(createInput).find('input').val() === '')
                 return;
       //Aqui es donde tengo la variable que captura el dato y lo imprime por pantalla
            var input= $(createInput).find('input').val();
     });

       };
     })(jQuery);
```

index.php

```
    @extends('templade')
    @section('content')
      <p align="right"><?php echo date('l j \of F Y H:i:s');?></p>

        <script src="js/proceso.js"></script>

         <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="carpeta" id="carp">
              <ul>
                  <li> </li>            
              </ul>                    
            </div>     
         </div>     

   <script>
(function ($) {
    function init() {
        $('.carpeta').Carpeta({
             codigoI: true,              
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();

 })(jQuery)

</script>

 @endsection
```

Ahora mi duda es como puedo enviar desde jquery el contenido de esa varible 'input' a mi documento php para despues almacenarla en la base de datos?

Answer (score 1):

cuando presiones tu  boton asignale submit y el agregale el (id) al formulario (formularioAgregar) con serialize te guarda todos los valores de los imput y lo guardas en una variable por ejemplo frm , luego tienes que darle la url de tu archivo php y en tu archivo php las recibes con $_post['name'] entre commilas va el nombre del input (name)

```
<button type="submit" name="enviar" id="agregar" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>

$( "#formularioAgregar" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var frm= $(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: 'index.php?accion=guardar',
       data: frm,
       success: function(data){
        $('#formularioAgregar')[0].reset();
        window.location.replace("index.php?accion=index");
        $('#resp').html('Se Agrego Correctamente El Status').show(200).delay(2500).hide(200);
       }
        })
    });
```

Comment: el codigo que me das de ejemplo tengo que ponerlo debajo de mi variable 'input' ??? o tiene que estar en otro lado?

Comment: en un archivo js  o crea un script en tu  pagina html <script> aqui metes todo el codigo</script>  , deberias aprender primero javascript y jquery para luego pasar por ajax

Comment: es que vi que en javascript podia enviar los contenidos por el metodo post pero hacia php nunca hice la prueba , y me indicaron que por ajax es mucho mas mejor hacerlo, pasando variables de jquery a php.

Comment: al reves,aprendiste pasar variables por php por el metodo post y por javascript no sabias. primero aprende javascript luego continua con jquery y al final ajax hay mucha informacion en la web .

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil , en mi punto de vista estas haciendo una mala practica con jquery, debido a que el envio de dato lo haces por POST
pero en url le mandas otra variable(metodo get). por otro lado desde jquery3 ya no se recomienda usar la función de devolución de llamada "success" si no la función "done"(asumiendo que se usa jquery3)